# Is it possible to make 'dynatree' responsive?

Tags: dynatree

I'm trying to integrate this component and am wondering if he can work well with responsive design. Does anybody have an advice on that?

Answer (score 0):

Its dynamic tree,

drag and drop functionality.
   You Can copy nodes.
   You can traverse one dynatree with another dynatree dynamically.
   functionality of sub-menu cut copy paste features.
   modes:  single select , multi-select and more.
   You can use theme change folder icons.

Comment: Go For it's the best library for tree.

Comment: Yes, it is responsive.